# Create a binary tree using an array of elements

Tags: c, binary-tree

So im trying to create a binary tree using a given array and then print the results in order,preorder and postorder but it seems i have done a mistake somewhere but as far as i can see things should be ok.

This is the result it prints out

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  #inorder
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  #postorder
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  #preorder
```

this is what ive done so far. Can somebody point out the mistake and maybe an advice on how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_s node_t;
struct node_s
{
    int key;
    node_t *left,*right;
};
node_t *new_node(int val)
{
    node_t *new;
    new= malloc(sizeof (node_t));
    if(new==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    new->key=val;
    new->left=NULL;
    new->right=NULL;
    return new;
}
void print_inorder(node_t *root)
{
    node_t *new=root;
    if (new != NULL) {
        print_inorder(new->left);
        printf("%d ",new->key);
        print_inorder(new->right);
    }
    return;

}
void print_postorder(node_t *root)
{
    node_t *new=root;
    if (new != NULL) {
        print_postorder(new->left);
        print_postorder(new->right);
        printf("%d ",new->key);
    }
    return;

}
void print_preorder(node_t *root)
{
    node_t *new=root;
    if (new != NULL) {
        printf("%d ",new->key);
        print_preorder(new->left);
        print_preorder(new->right);
    }
    return;

}
node_t *insert_node(node_t *root,int val)
{
     if(root==NULL)
            return new_node(val);
     else
     {
         if(val<root->left)
             root->left= insert_node(root->left,val);
         else if(val>root->left)
             root->right= insert_node(root->right,val);
     }
    return root;
}
int main() {

    int n;
    int v[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    node_t *root=NULL;
    FILE *file;
    file= fopen("file","r");
    if(file==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        root= insert_node(root,v[i]);
    }

    print_inorder(root);
    printf("\n");
    print_postorder(root);
    printf("\n");
    print_preorder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why open the file? You never use it and don't close it. Turn up the warning level in your compiler and pay attention to them. https://godbolt.org/z/nsaErdz5s Should you be comparing the pointer value or the key value it points to? `if(val<root->left)` You should be checking for NULL as well.

Comment: @RetiredNinja as for why i opened a file it was because the array was originally stored in a file and i forgot to delete the line when i changed it to post it here. As for the second it was indeed a misstep on my part but i changed it to ```(val<root->key)``` and the result is still the same. Or is it supposed to be printed out like that

Comment: From the outputs, It looks like your code made a linked list.

Comment: @user3386109 But isnt that the case with binary trees? Just another type of linked list?

Comment: Checking the code I see that there's no code to balance the tree, and the nodes are inserted in sorted order. So yes, you've made a linked list. Try changing the array to `int v[]={5,3,1,4,2,8,6,7,9,10};`

Comment: A linked list has only one child per node, a binary tree has two. If you never use one of the children, then you've lost all of the benefits of a binary tree.

Comment: @user3386109 then i suppose the rest looks ok?

Comment: I only skimmed the code, but the parts that I looked at seem ok. Having said that, let me point out that keeping the tree balanced is 99% of the work.

Comment: @user3386109 fair enough. but for now im just working on getting used to the binary trees and later on ill work on the balance but ill heed your advice

Comment: Also note, with your `v[]` array sorted, you will not have a LEFT branch to your tree off the `root` node. All your data is stored on the RIGHT branch of `root`. Try unsorted input, e.g. `int v[] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };` (or similar). Do you understand why your current sorted `v[]` only populates the right branch of your tree?

Comment: Matter of taste, but there is no need for `node_t *new=root;` in your `pre`, `post`, `in` order traversals, just use `root` (or whatever you pass as the parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save time, **enable all compiler warnings**.

Problems identified in seconds!
Code has at least this problem:

**Compare between integer and pointer**

```
// warning: comparison between pointer and integer
if (val < root->left) // Bad
```

Likely wanted:

```
if (val < root->key)
```

Likewise with `else if (val > root->left)`

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to make a balanced binary tree from a sorted array, you could try this recursive strategy:

```
node_t* createBinaryTree(int* items, size_t count) {
    size_t mid = count/2;
    node_t* newNode = NULL;

    if (count == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    newNode = new_node(items[mid]);

    if (count > 1) {
        newNode->left = createBinaryTree(items, mid);
        newNode->right = createBinaryTree(items+mid+1, count-mid-1);
    }

    return newNode;
}
```

Then you can create the tree as follows:

```
int v[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
size_t count = sizeof(v)/sizeof(*v); // 10
node_t* root = createBinaryTree(v, count);
```

If the array isn't already sorted, you sort it as follows using the standard C library function qsort as follows:

```
qsort(v, count, sizeof(*v), compareFunction)
```

prior to calling `createBinaryTree`. Where compareFunction is a previously defined function that looks like this:

```
int compareFunction(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    int v1 = *(int*)p1;    
    int v2 = *(int*)p2;
    return (v1 - v2);
}
```

Comment: Really like your approach.  Candidate simplification: `node_t* createBinaryTree(int *items, size_t count) { node_t *newNode = NULL; if (count > 0) { size_t mid = count / 2;     newNode = new_node(items[mid]);  newNode->left = createBinaryTree(items, mid);    newNode->right = createBinaryTree(items + mid + 1, count - mid - 1);  } return newNode;`
}
`

Comment: Minor: `v1 - v2` risks overflow.  `(v1 > v2) - (v1 < v2)` always works

Answer (score -1):

My answer seems to be able to create binary trees of any type.

If anyone can tell me where there are problems with my answer, I would be happy to make corrections.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_s node_t;
struct node_s
{
    char key;
    node_t *left,*right;
};


/*
node_t *new_node(char val)
{
    node_t *new;
    new= malloc(sizeof (node_t));
    if(new==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    new->key=val;
    new->left=NULL;
    new->right=NULL;
    return new;
}
*/


void ClearTree(node_t** root)
{ 
    if(*root) 
    {
        if((*root)->left)
        {
            ClearTree(&(*root)->left);
        }
        if((*root)->right) 
        {
            ClearTree(&(*root)->right); 
        }

        free(*root);
        *root=NULL;
    }
}

void print_inorder(node_t *root)
{
    node_t *new=root;
    if (new == NULL)
       return;
    print_inorder(new->left);
    printf("%c ",new->key);
    print_inorder(new->right);

}
void print_postorder(node_t *root)
{
    node_t *new=root;
    if (new == NULL)
        return;
    print_postorder(new->left);
    print_postorder(new->right);
    printf("%c ",new->key);
    

}
void print_preorder(node_t *root)
{
    node_t *new=root;
    if (new == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%c ",new->key);
    print_preorder(new->left);
    print_preorder(new->right);
    

}
void CreateTree(node_t** root)
{
    char v[]={'A','B','#','D','#','#','C','#','#'};
    static int i = 0;
    if(v[i] == '#'){
        *root = NULL;
        i++;
    }
    else{
        *root = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if(NULL == *root){
            printf("No space\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        (*root)->key = v[i];
        i++;
        CreateTree(&(*root) -> left);
        CreateTree(&(*root) -> right);
    }
}
int main() {

    node_t *root=NULL;
    
//    FILE *file;
//    file= fopen("file","r");
//    if(file==NULL)
//    {
//        exit(1);
//    }    

    CreateTree(&root);

    printf("preorder:  ");
    print_preorder(root);
    printf("\n");

    printf("inorder:   ");
    print_inorder(root);
    printf("\n");

    printf("postorder: ");
    print_postorder(root);
    printf("\n");

    ClearTree(&root);

    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output:

```
preorder:  A B D C 
inorder:   B D A C 
postorder: D B C A
```

As number,see below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_s node_t;
struct node_s
{
    char key;
    node_t *left,*right;
};


/*
node_t *new_node(char val)
{
    node_t *new;
    new= malloc(sizeof (node_t));
    if(new==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    new->key=val;
    new->left=NULL;
    new->right=NULL;
    return new;
}
*/


void ClearTree(node_t** root)
{ 
    if(*root) 
    {
        if((*root)->left)
        {
            ClearTree(&(*root)->left);
        }
        if((*root)->right) 
        {
            ClearTree(&(*root)->right); 
        }

        free(*root);
        *root=NULL;
    }
}

void print_inorder(node_t *root)
{
    node_t *new=root;
    if (new == NULL)
       return;
    print_inorder(new->left);
    printf("%d ",new->key);
    print_inorder(new->right);

}
void print_postorder(node_t *root)
{
    node_t *new=root;
    if (new == NULL)
        return;
    print_postorder(new->left);
    print_postorder(new->right);
    printf("%d ",new->key);
    

}
void print_preorder(node_t *root)
{
    node_t *new=root;
    if (new == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%d ",new->key);
    print_preorder(new->left);
    print_preorder(new->right);
    

}
void CreateTree(node_t** root)
{
    int v[]={1,2,4,8,'#','#',9,'#','#',5,10,'#','#','#',3,6,'#','#',7,'#','#'};
    static int i = 0;
    if(v[i] == '#'){
        *root = NULL;
        i++;
    }
    else{
        *root = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if(NULL == *root){
            printf("No space\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        (*root)->key = v[i];
        i++;
        CreateTree(&(*root) -> left);
        CreateTree(&(*root) -> right);
    }
}
int main() {

    node_t *root=NULL;
    
//    FILE *file;
//    file= fopen("file","r");
//    if(file==NULL)
//    {
//        exit(1);
//    }    

    CreateTree(&root);

    printf("preorder:  ");
    print_preorder(root);
    printf("\n");

    printf("inorder:   ");
    print_inorder(root);
    printf("\n");

    printf("postorder: ");
    print_postorder(root);
    printf("\n");

    ClearTree(&root);

    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output

```
preorder:  1 2 4 8 9 5 10 3 6 7 
inorder:   8 4 9 2 10 5 1 6 3 7 
postorder: 8 9 4 10 5 2 6 7 3 1
```

Comment: I'm not your downvote, but curiously I've never heard of adding a special character marking the termination of a node in a basic binary tree. (yes, useful in more specific exotic trees like a ternary search tree for prefix searching, but not in a basic tree as here).  Do you have a reference or citation to where that information comes from?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Do you understand Chinese? My information that reference or citation comes from Chinese. I'm Chinese. I think my answer is right,it can get correct result.I don't understand why someone would downvote my answer when I believe my answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. No offense meant. I was honestly just curious to learn what you were referring too. And again, I'm not one of your downvotes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Although adding a special character as a termination node may seem a bit crude, I feel like it can solve the problem. There is a saying that goes "it doesn't matter if a cat is black or white, as long as it catches mice."