# Pointer of a Pointer in C: How to use them in RB Trees?

Tags: c, pointers, red-black-tree

I have seen online many people showing their own implementation of RB trees in C. Most of them, when calling any function, use the parameter `struct Node **root` referring to a struct node like this:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    char color;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *parent;
} Node;
```

Why people do so? Why `struct Node *root` isn't enough? Can you please give an explanation of the meaning of a pointer of a pointer in this specific case and add some valid examples?

Comment: Start with a simple unbalanced tree. Pointers to pointers (they are *not* called "double pointers" ) are useful with unbalanced trees just as much. Then work your way up to balanced trees such as RB.

Comment: In C all arguments to functions are passed by value. Which means the value in the call is copied into the functions local argument variable. By using the pointer-to operator `&` and pointer to pointer as argument, one can emulate pass by reference. Either that, or it's passing a jagged array. Without more context it's hard to say more.

Comment: Because the functions may change the value of `struct Node *root` the function needs a **pointer to `struct Node *root`**. In other words, it needs `struct Node **root` and the caller will pass `&root`. In the function you'll find code like `*root = new_root`.

Comment: ^^.  And note that there are alternatives, chiefly: (1) functions receive `struct Node *root` as a parameter, and *return* the new root; the caller then is obligated to do this: `root = tree_function(root, other_params ...)`. (2) instead of representing the overall tree as a bare root pointer, represent it with a structure that contains the root pointer as a member; the caller then passes a pointer to *that* structure: `tree_function(&the_tree, other_params ...)`.

Comment: There will be some variable initialized something like `struct Node *root = NULL;` somewhere in the code that uses the RBT functions. The null pointer value represents an empty tree. As the code calls the RBT functions to insert and remove nodes, the value of `root` needs to change to point to the node that ends up at the top of the tree, or change to `NULL` when the tree becomes empty. Every insertion or removal operation *could* require `root` to be changed. Passing `&root` to the RBT functions allows the functions to modify the value of `root` in place.

Answer (score 0):

If a linked list's first node is `struct Node *root` type, then now you want to insert a node where the first node before, so you will change the first node pointed, now you need to use `struct Node ** root`.

See more details at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76543896/create-a-binary-tree-using-an-array-of-elements/76544350#76544350). That answer use you mentioned type like: `struct Node ** root`. (Ignore that answer have 2 vote down.) That answer's code can beautifully run at https://godbolt.org/z/bTdqE8Pcv.

Hope this can help you.